# How do I deploy a ML model trained on SageMaker, to a local machine to run predict?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

I been looking around at various post about deploying SageMaker models locally, but they have to be tied to an AWS notebook instances in order to run predict/serve locally (AWS SageMaker Python SDK). This defeats the actual intent of running the Sagemaker trained model fully offline. Also there are some others who tried unpickling the tar.gz file on S3, followed by wrapping the contents to be deployed locally. However the process seems to be very restricted to certain types of models such as XGBoost and MXnet. Hence is there any way to deploy a SageMaker trained model offline without dependency to a Sagemaker notebook instance? Any form of advice would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are you asking with regard to SaegMaker build-in algorithms? or using your own framework (TF, Pytorch, ...) in SageMaker?

Comment: Hi Gili Nachum. I am refering to both SageMaker build-in algorithms and also own framework in Sagemaker. Could we deploy/serve the model trained on Sagemaker completely offline without any dependency to AWS after training? If not what are the limitations?

Comment: @Zach did you find any relevant solution/blog for this.?

Comment: @Srini not atm, still searching for the answer as well

Comment: Did anyone find a good answer to this? I have a colab notebook about installing TensorFlow and serving locally if that helps. https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/tfx/blob/master/docs/tutorials/serving/rest_simple.ipynb

Answer (score 1):

I've deployed PyTorch models locally via [Amazon SageMaker Local Mode](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/use-the-amazon-sagemaker-local-mode-to-train-on-your-notebook-instance/). I believe the same process works for other ML frameworks that have official SageMaker containers. You can run the same Docker containers locally that SageMaker uses when deploying your model on AWS infrastructure.

The docs for deploying a Sagemaker endpoint locally for inference are a bit scattered. A summary:

1. Use local versions of API clients: normally, you use `botocore.client.SageMaker` and `botocore.client.SageMakerRuntime` classes to use SageMaker from Python. To use SageMaker locally, use `sagemaker.local.LocalSagemakerClient()` and `sagemaker.local.LocalSagemakerRuntimeClient()` instead.
2. You can use a local `tar.gz` model file if you wish.
3. Set the `instance_type` to `local` when deploying the model.

I wrote [How to setup a local AWS SageMaker environment for PyTorch](https://booklet.ai/blog/aws-sagemaker-pytorch-local-dev-flow/), which goes in detail on how this works.

Comment: Are your pytorch models trained on SageMaker? I am refering to deploying SageMaker trained models totally off-line without calling Sagemaker platform/having any sort of connectivity to SageMaker instance. Reason is that hosting an instance cost money, and is an unneeded dependency that could be get rid off after training.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have trained a model using Amazon SageMaker you'll have a Model entry. The model will point to a model artifact in S3. This tag.gz file has the model weights. The format of the file depends on the framework (tensorflow/pytorch/mxnet/...) you've used to train the model. If you've used SageMaker built-in algorithms, most of them are implemented with MXNet, or XGBoost, so you could use the relevant model serving software to run the model.
If you need serving software, you could run the SageMaker deeplearning containers in inference mode, on your local inference server. Or use open-source serving software like TFServing, or load the model in-memory.

Comment: Hi Gili Nachum. Yes i do know that the model weights are stored as a tar.gz file in S3 branch. However my question is how do you serve or run the trained SageMaker model offline on your own server without the use of any SageMaker for deployment. In order to run a deep learning model you need the model artifacts (weights) and also the image in order to replicate and deploy the model locally right? So is there a way to actually a way to deploy the models offline WITHOUT any dependency on AWS. An example would be great as well. Thank you.